# How to gracefully handle differences in command options between different versions?

Tags: shell-script, command, options, compatibility

Inspired by [What is the difference between “base64 -b0” in macOS versions prior to macOS 13 (Ventura) and “base64 -i” in macOS 13 (Ventura)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1754224/what-is-the-difference-between-base64-b0-in-macos-versions-prior-to-macos-13)

Are there common ways to avoid the script breaking on a system with a different version of a command, at least when you know what the differences are? Would checking the command `--version` or `--help` output and calling it with different options make sense?

Comment: That's what the `configure` scripts of a lot of software do (based on [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf#Approach)). Run [a bunch of commands with different options and test inputs](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.72/autoconf.html#Existing-Tests) to determine which particular toolset and release they have.

Comment: Having a build step for a few-line shell script seems like overkill.

Comment: Maybe. You asked if X made sense, I said a commonly-used tool Y does X. Now whether you use X in your software or Y is up to you. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯